# Внедрение MySQL непосредственно в проект на Itellig IDEA

Tags: java, mysqli

**Суть проблемы** Мне нужна помощь как в принципе подключить MySQL в проект Intellij IDEA Comunity для роботы. Меня интересуют все тонкости  ибо я первый раз работаю с mySQL. И второй вопрос как сделать так что-бы пользователь инсталировавший мое приложение  база не отвалилась и не выдавала исключение о том что её по такому то пути не найдено. Короче интересует то как зашить базу в сам проект что-бы пользователь мог работать с ней без самой базы на пк

Answer (score 0):

MySQL в данном случае плохой вариант. Для локальнлого сохранения данных лучше использовать Realm или SQLite.